# Trim a string purely to text, without leaving any whitespace in PHP?

Tags: php, jquery, jquery-file-upload

I am having an image upload script, which works fine so far. It runs with jQuery fileupload. The PHP script generates a new name for the uploaded image and gives it out through `exit($imgname);`. Strangely I always get a response with many whitespaces like you can see in the picture.

***To the screenshot:***
[image: Many whitespaces, but why?]***

My whole website uses jQuery and I thought about using $.trim() to just trim the result to plain text, but I don't know if this is a great idea since I don't think that this works for any common browser.

Additional:
The most strange thing about this is, that it worked in the past just fine without any whitespaces. Today I uploaded something and suddenly it does something like this...

PHP:

```
$upload  = $image->upload(); 
$imgname = $image->getName();
$imgmime = $image->getMime();
$fullimgname = $imgname . "." . $imgmime;

if($upload){
    // POST TO DATABASE ETC.

    exit($fullimgname);
}
```

Comment: Post the PHP code that generates `$imgname`...

Comment: It's a library called Bulleproof that I've found on github.
https://github.com/samayo/bulletproof

Comment: And this library works without you having written a single line of code?

Comment: Edited it to the question

Comment: what if you try with simple quote like :
$fullimgname = trim($imgname . '.' . $imgmime);

Comment: @MOHAMMEDYASSINEChabli Still that many whitespaces...

Comment: don't you use trim in jquery ?

Comment: I do, that works. But I thought maybe that doing it in PHP would be better for any browser. Atleast for older browser versions

Comment: can you print the $fullimgname and check if it has whitespace ?

Comment: The spaces may come from somewhere else above the exit line. Do you have some white spaces outside the `<?php` and `?>` brackets?

Comment: @MOHAMMEDYASSINEChabli I did, it doesn't have any.

Comment: @LouysPatriceBessette OH MY, yeah it did. I have a file included and there I've added some whitespaces after the <?php ?> brackets. God so stupid. Thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The white paces may come from somewhere else in the PHP file...

Look for spaces that would be outside the `<?php` and `?>` brackets.

Like this, for example:

```
        // <-- 4 tabs on this line
<?php
$upload  = $image->upload(); 
$imgname = $image->getName();
$imgmime = $image->getMime();
$fullimgname = $imgname . "." . $imgmime;

if($upload){
  // POST TO DATABASE ETC.

  exit($fullimgname);
}
```

Comment: Thank you, that exactly was the problem. Because of an included file that had whitespaces.

Answer (score 0):

Try to use regex, because it might consider full unicode charset, etc:

```
$imgname = preg_replace('/^\s+/u', "", $imgname);
```

Although it looks like`ltrim()` should be enough.